# Navigation Bar with unordered list

Tags: css, html, navigation, unordered

This question should be simple enough, taking an html class and ran in this problem while trying to complete an assignment. I made my navigation bar by making an unordered list, formatted it using CSS, but now I can't make an ordered list on the page because of the formatting I did for the navigation bar.

Comment: Simply fixed, add a class to your unordered list, then change your CSS to use that class.

Comment: You probably want to add an id to your HTML, or create a class and apply the class to your HTML.  Either way, we need to see what you DID do so that we can better comment on a solution.

Comment: When I create a class for <ul> it won't display inline. The only way I've been able to display the navigation bar inline is by making a <li> tag.

Answer (score 1):

The navbar HTML should be:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="home.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a>/</li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

And the CSS should be:

```
ul#navbar {
    display:inline;
    /* Any other CSS you want */
}
ul#navbar li {
    display:inline;
}
```

And then that CSS won't affect any other ULs you create.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your generic list styles and then override them for your navigation bar:

```
ul { /* Basic UL styles here */ }

#main-navigation ul { /* Navigation menu styles here (assumes a container with ID 'main-navigation') */ }
```

Comment: When I create a class for <ul> it won't display inline. The only way I've been able to display the navigation bar inline is by making a <li> tag

Comment: Well, same concept applies. Write your base list styles first (against the tag in question) Then write more specific CSS for your navigation bar.